# MSMQ and Active Directory Integration

Tags: c#, active-directory, msmq

I've got 2 applications that utilize MSMQ to pass information between 2 servers.

One posts new information hourly and runs without issue.

The other app runs once nightly and seems to be intermittently failing with the following error message:

```
A connection with Active Directory cannot be established. Verify that there are
sufficient permissions to perform this operation.
```

Re-running this task manually completes with no issue.

When we first installed MSMQ on our servers we took the default setup, which resulted in Active Directory Integration being installed.

I've read a few posts that address this issue and they recommend that I uninstall this component as well as add a registry key to disable this as well.

[Nine Tips to Enterprise-proof MSMQ](http://www.devx.com/enterprise/Article/22314/0/page/1) was a well written article that gave me a lot of info.

My question is whether there are any additional steps I would need to take if I was to uninstall this?

Is there anything that this component does that I'm not aware of?

My consumer queue paths are formatted like "DIRECT=TCP:XXX.XXX.X.XXX\UploadQ".  Would I need to modify these?

Thanks again for all the help.

~Jim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Active Directory seems to be the devil when dealing with MSMQ.  We got around any Active Directory issues by using private queues and bypassing active directory all together.

This approach also improves the performance of the MSMQ's in regards to speed.

Comment: This is what I ended up going with.  Convert any public queues to private, and scheduled the removal of Active Directory Integration for the next server reboot.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the task scheduler you're using is running with a user account that doesn't have the permissions.  That would explain why it works when you run it manually.

Comment: Very good point, but I don't think that's it.  Our current workaround is to run the sched. task 3 times 10 minutes apart; sometimes it runs fine on the first try, sometimes the 2nd, sometimes the 3rd, and when all 3 fail, we run it manually.  If it truly was a permissions issue, wouldn't it fail all 3 times?

Comment: Ahhh. Could be timeouts accessing AD for authentication?  Is there anything in the event logs?

Comment: That's what I was thinking.  This job runs overnight when there's a lot of other system processing going on, so our thinking was that AD was somehow busy at the time this kicked off.  Event logs just show the message I posted above unfortunately.